# I'm getting the errorNum :8 while sending the push notifications to ios devices

Tags: ios, node.js, npm, apple-push-notifications, apn

```js
var apn = require('apn');
var gcm = require('android-gcm');


export default function notification( devicetype, devicetoken, alert, userid, action, profilepic,  image, youtubeimage, id ) {

   
    if(devicetoken != "(null)") {
        var androidApiKey = '', cert = '', key = '', passphrase = '';

        if(process.env.NODE_ENV.toLowerCase() == "production") {
          cert = '/../config/ios_support/apns-cert.pem';
          key = '/../config/ios_support/apns-key.pem';
          passphrase = '*****';
          androidApiKey = "*******";
        }
        else {
          cert = '/../config/ios_support/apns-dev-cert.pem';
          key = '/../config/ios_support/apns-dev-key.pem';
          passphrase = '*******';
          androidApiKey = "********";
        }


        if(devicetype == "ios"){
            var myDevice = new apn.Device(devicetoken);

            var note = new apn.Notification();
            note.badge = 1;
            note.sound = "notification-beep.wav";

            note.alert = alert;

            note.category = "respond"

            note.device = myDevice;

            note.payload = { 'action': action, 'userid': userid, 'profilepic': profilepic, 'id':id};

            console.log("note.payload: "+ JSON.stringify(note.payload));

            //, 'WatchKit Simulator Actions': [{"title": "Show", "identifier": "showButtonAction"}]

            var callback = function (errorNum, notification) {
                console.log('Error is:.....', errorNum);
            }


            var options = {
                gateway: 'gateway.push.apple.com',
                //'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com',
                // this URL is different for Apple's Production Servers and changes when you go to production
                errorCallback: callback,
                cert: __dirname.split('src/')[0] + cert,
                key: __dirname.split('src/')[0] + key,
                passphrase: passphrase,
                port: ****,
                cacheLength: 100
            }

            var apnsConnection = new apn.Connection(options);
            apnsConnection.sendNotification(note);
        }
        else if(devicetype == "android"){

            var gcmObject = new gcm.AndroidGcm(androidApiKey);
            var message = new gcm.Message({
                registration_ids: [devicetoken],
                data: {
                    body: alert,
                    action: action,
                    userid: userid,
                    profilepic: profilepic,
                    id: id
                }
            });

            gcmObject.send(message, function(err, response) {
                if(err) console.error("error: "+err);
        //        else    console.log("response: "+response);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

> Here is my code. In console I'm getting all the stuff and device token is also fine. Android mobiles are getting notifications. But notifications are not sending to ios devices. I'm getting this error in console : Error is:...... 8.
>   One more thing is, for the same device I'm able to send the notification for other functionality with other code.
>   Really I'm pulling my hair out for this issue. And can't understand what's wrong with my code. Anyone please give solution for this.

Comment: Please check with your server this https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT203609

Comment: Thanks for the reply @PPL. I'm using the port: 2195.

Comment: I've tested in : https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher. Notifications are sending while testing from pusher.That means certificates are fine and device token is also fine. But while using my code notifications are not sending. What's wrong in my code??

Answer (score 3):

You are using an old version. Apple has changed some thing in the push api last year in march i guess.
Also you forgot to set your `topic` which is mandetory for apn push Notifications

Try something like this for you `if (devicetype == "ios")` block

```
if(devicetype == "ios") {
    var myDevice = new apn.Device(devicetoken);

    var note = new apn.Notification();
    note.badge = 1;
    note.sound = "notification-beep.wav";
    note.alert = alert;
    note.category = "respond"
    note.payload = {'action': action, 'userid': userid, 'profilepic': profilepic, 'id': id};

    //you missed this one i guess
    note.topic = "<your-app-bundle-id>";

    console.log("note.payload: " + JSON.stringify(note.payload));

    //, 'WatchKit Simulator Actions': [{"title": "Show", "identifier": "showButtonAction"}]

    var callback = function(errorNum, notification) {
        console.log('Error is:.....', errorNum);
    }


    var options = {
        token: {
            key: __dirname.split('src/')[0] + cert,
            keyId: __dirname.split('src/')[0] + key,
            teamId: "developer-team-id"
        },
        production: false // for development
    };

    var apnProvider = new apn.Provider(options);

    apnProvider.send(note, myDevice).then( (result) => {
        // see documentation for an explanation of result
        console.log(result);
    });

}
```

You can find the documentation here [apn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apn)

Comment: HI @BraveButter,  issue got already fixed. Thanks for the reply.